# Change classname based on slider index position

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-slick

I want to change the **className** based on the selected slider **data-index** position in https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-slick-slider-issues which is making use of *React-slick-slider*.

Suppose if the user hovers on the first image, the image **data-index** value is 0 and I want to push the image above the slider and **onMouseOut** the image will go back to its original place in the slider and do this for the last image as well.

For all the images in between the first and last images, they will be pushed down. currently hovering on an image they will be pushed down and **onMouseOut** they will go back to its original place in the slider.

If **className** by default is ***unique-image*** can it be changed for the First Image as ***unique-image First***, if its the last image then **className** should be ***unique-image Last*** and for all the in-between images it should be ***unique-image between***. is this something that can be achieved?

Comment: Are you mapping over the images to display them? Then you could use a tertiary operator check whether the index is 0 or the last in the list.

Comment: Yes Im mapping over the images, can you share a code snippet?

Answer (score 0):

As you are mapping over the images, you could use a tertiary operator:

```
const images = [...something];

images.map((image, key) => <img className={`unique-image ${key === 0 ? "First" : key == images.length - 1 ? "Last" : ""}`} {...otherProps} />
```

So you use the key from the map function to check for the first and last element and add the respective classes when reached.